# How can I add global variables for Twig in Slim 3.5?

Tags: php, twig, slim

In Symfony, I'm used to using `{{ app.user.username }}` in any view. Can I do something like this in Slim?

Currently I am adding the user to the `$container['user']` and passing it into every view with `view->render($response, 'index.html.twig', ['user' => $this->user])`.

In other words, can I add `user` as a global variable for Twig? I saw many similar questions but not had a solution I was able to use.

Comment: I think you should add class that receive current user instead of user object. User data can change during request.

Answer (score 8):

How about `$container['view']->addGlobal('user', $this->user);` ?

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: If not using symfony, you may need to use `$container['view']->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('base', 'xxx');`

Answer (score 2):

I used this to expose the path in the **{{ current_path }}** variable:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container["view"] = function ($container) use ($menu) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig("../templates");
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace("index.php", "", $container["request"]->getUri()->getBasePath()), "/");
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($container["router"], $basePath));
    $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("current_path", $container["request"]->getUri()->getPath());
    return $view;
};
```

This follows the approach described in the [Templates](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding this line to my dependencies (after i register Twig)

```
$container['view']['user'] = $_SESSION['user'];
```

This works well. I can get username with `{{ user.username }}`. I don't have a clue how secure it is to do sessions this way, but it works.